# How to save and restore Keras LSTM model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, prediction

I have trained a LSTM network to predict stock price.But I don't know how to save and restore it.

Follow is my code:

```
CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 12
CONST_TESTING_CASES = 5


def dataNormalization(data):
    return [(datum - data[0]) / data[0] for datum in data]


def dataDeNormalization(data, base):
    return [(datum + 1) * base for datum in data]


def getDeepLearningData(ticker):
    # Step 1. Load data
    data = pandas.read_csv('./data/Intraday/' + ticker + '.csv')[
        'close'].tolist()
    # Step 2. Building Training data
    dataTraining = []
    for i in range(len(data) - CONST_TESTING_CASES * CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH):
        dataSegment = data[i:i + CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH + 1]
        dataTraining.append(dataNormalization(dataSegment))

    dataTraining = numpy.array(dataTraining)
    numpy.random.shuffle(dataTraining)
    X_Training = dataTraining[:, :-1]
    Y_Training = dataTraining[:, -1]

    # Step 3. Building Testing data
    X_Testing = []
    Y_Testing_Base = []
    for i in range(CONST_TESTING_CASES, 0, -1):
        dataSegment = data[-(i + 1) * CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH:-i * CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH]
        Y_Testing_Base.append(dataSegment[0])
        X_Testing.append(dataNormalization(dataSegment))

    Y_Testing = data[-CONST_TESTING_CASES * CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH:]

    X_Testing = numpy.array(X_Testing)
    Y_Testing = numpy.array(Y_Testing)

    # Step 4. Reshape for deep learning
    X_Training = numpy.reshape(X_Training, (X_Training.shape[0], X_Training.shape[1], 1))
    X_Testing = numpy.reshape(X_Testing, (X_Testing.shape[0], X_Testing.shape[1], 1))

    return X_Training, Y_Training, X_Testing, Y_Testing, Y_Testing_Base


def predict(model, X):
    predictionsNormalized = []

    for i in range(len(X)):
        data = X[i]
        result = []

        for j in range(CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH):
            predicted = model.predict(data[numpy.newaxis, :, :])[0, 0]
            result.append(predicted)
            data = data[1:]
            data = numpy.insert(data, [CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH - 1], predicted, axis=0)

        predictionsNormalized.append(result)

    return predictionsNormalized


def plotResults(Y_Hat, Y):
    plt.plot(Y)

    for i in range(len(Y_Hat)):
        padding = [None for _ in range(i * CONST_TRAINING_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)]
        plt.plot(padding + Y_Hat[i])

    plt.show()


def predictLSTM(ticker):
    # Step 1. Load data
    X_Training, Y_Training, X_Testing, Y_Testing, Y_Testing_Base = getDeepLearningData(ticker)

    # Step 2. Build model
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_shape=(None, 1),
        units=50,
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        200,
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(units=1))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

    # Step 3. Train model
    model.fit(X_Training, Y_Training,
              batch_size=512,
              epochs=27,
              validation_split=0.05)

    # Step 4. Predict
    predictionsNormalized = predict(model, X_Testing)

    # Step 5. De-nomalize
    predictions = []
    for i, row in enumerate(predictionsNormalized):
        predictions.append(dataDeNormalization(row, Y_Testing_Base[i]))

    # Step 6. Plot
    plotResults(predictions, Y_Testing)


predictLSTM(ticker='IBM')
```

Now all the come out of the prediction are all history data.But what I want is to use this model to predict the future price.Any friend can help with specific code.

Any friend can help me with this,really appreciate!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The procedure on saving a model and its weights is described in the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model). Here a summary for you:

- In order to save the model and the weights use the model's `save()` function.

```
    from keras.models import load_model
    
    model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
    del model  # deletes the existing model
    
    # returns a compiled model
    # identical to the previous one
    model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

- For only storing the model definition, you can obtain its description as a JSON or YAML:

```
    # save as JSON
    json_string = model.to_json()
    
    # save as YAML
    yaml_string = model.to_yaml()
```

to load it again, simply apply

```
    # model reconstruction from JSON:
    from keras.models import model_from_json
    model = model_from_json(json_string)
    
    # model reconstruction from YAML:
    from keras.models import model_from_yaml
    model = model_from_yaml(yaml_string)
```

- In case you only want to store the weights, use

```
    model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')  # to store
    model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')  # to load
```

Once tho model is loaded again, you can use it by applying it on previously loaded data, like

```
predicted_output = model.predict(input_data, batch_size=BS)
```

Comment: Hi friends,when try to     predicted_output = model.predict(newdata, batch_size=512)

Comment: Hi dear friend,can you help me with this relative question?Appreciate a lot!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509570/how-to-solve-save-and-restore-keras-lstm-model-error

Comment: @Martin   Do we need to store all the parameters in LSTM? Is there any other alternative when I have LSTM cells as large as 1K?

Comment: you have to store all. Otherwise you loose information gained from training.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. First you have to save the model's json, then the model's weights. After saving your weights,structure and full keras model delete your previously created model.

```
from pathlib import Path
# Save neural network structure
model_structure = model.to_json()
f = Path("C:\\----yourfolderpath.json")
f.write_text(model_structure)
print('done')

# Save neural network's trained weights
your_model.save_weights("C:\\---------yourfolderpath_weights.h5")
print('done')

# or you can save the full model via:
your_model.save('C:\\---------yourfolderpath_fullkeras_model.h5')

#delete your model in memory
del your_model

#Know to load your model use:
my_new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("path to model")


#compile my_new_model:
my_new_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend!Can you show me the more specific step or code of 'initialize your model by compiling it' I'm really very new in deep learning.For example how can I predict ibm stock by 'initialize your model by compiling it'  really very preciate it!

Comment: Your welcome. I am new as-well. You would need to call 'model.predict()` here is the documentation: https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: Hi dear friend,can you help me with this relative question?Appreciate a lot!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509570/how-to-solve-save-and-restore-keras-lstm-model-error